# Database architecture for millions of new rows per day

Tags: mysql, database, scalability, analytics, data-warehouse

I need to implement a custom-developed web analytics service for large number of websites. The key entities here are:

- Website
- Visitor

Each unique visitor will have have a single row in the database with information like landing page, time of day, OS, Browser, referrer, IP, etc.

I will need to do aggregated queries on this database such as 'COUNT all visitors who have Windows as OS and came from Bing.com'

I have hundreds of websites to track and the number of visitors for those websites range from a few hundred a day to few million a day. In total, I expect this database to grow by about a million rows per day.

My questions are:

1) Is MySQL a good database for this purpose?

2) What could be a good architecture? I am thinking of creating a new table for each website. Or perhaps start with a single table and then spawn a new table (daily) if number of rows in an existing table exceed 1 million (is my assumption correct). My only worry is that if a table grows too big, the SQL queries can get dramatically slow. So, what is the maximum number of rows I should store per table? Moreover, is there a limit on number of tables that MySQL can handle.

3) Is it advisable to do aggregate queries over millions of rows? I'm ready to wait for a couple of seconds to get results for such queries. Is it  a good practice or is there any other way to do aggregate queries?

In a nutshell, **I am trying a design a large scale data-warehouse kind of setup which will be write heavy**. If you know about any published case studies or reports, that'll be great!

Comment: If you have already designed your database. Can you share database design ?

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking larger volumes of data, then look at [MySQL partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html). For these tables, a partition by data/time would certainly help performance. There's a decent article about partitioning [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html).

Look at creating two separate databases: one for all raw data for the writes with minimal indexing; a second for reporting using the aggregated values; with either a batch process to update the reporting database from the raw data database, or use replication to do that for you.

**EDIT**

If you want to be really clever with your aggregation reports, create a set of aggregation tables ("today", "week to date", "month to date", "by year"). Aggregate from raw data to "today" either daily or in "real time"; aggregate from "by day" to "week to date" on a nightly basis; from "week to date" to "month to date" on a weekly basis, etc. When executing queries, join (UNION) the appropriate tables for the date ranges you're interested in.

**EDIT #2**

Rather than one table per client, we work with one database schema per client. Depending on the size of the client, we might have several schemas in a single database instance, or a dedicated database instance per client. We use separate schemas for raw data collection, and for aggregation/reporting for each client. We run multiple database servers, restricting each server to a single database instance. For resilience, databases are replicated across multiple servers and load balanced for improved performance.

Comment: Actually aggregation will happen on arbitrary columns. So, it is not just about number of unique visitors or repeat visitors, but a user can select any combination of variables (OS, browser, referrer, time of day) to do segmentation. That's what makes it bit difficult because I need to have access to raw data for that.

Comment: My business is providing exactly this kind of information (and a great deal more than just landing page - such as value of spend, basket abandonment) for some very large clients (the AA, several major banks and insurance companies, large tour operators), so we get similarly large (millions of rows per day) volumes of data. We run on Oracle rather than MySQL, but many of the principles are the same. We prefer to provide drill-down reports, which allows use to use aggregated data for a high level report, with selective "drilldown" to the underlying raw data.

Comment: do you store historical data forever? Or do you have a purging strategy (say delete all data older than 100 days)?

Comment: We actually maintain all data to a limit of 7 years, after which time it is archived. Seven years probably excessive, given the rate at which the web evolves; 2 or (possibly) 3 years should be more than adequate; but we have a couple of clients want 7 years, and it's easier to apply that rule across the complete client base. It's useful to have several years for running "comparative" reports (e.g. comparing this July figures with previous July figures) and for trending reports.

Comment: Addendum to 7 years... besides, we can charge for maintaining the extra data volumes (if it's been explicitly requested)

Comment: @MarkBaker Can you share your database design and processes?

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions in a database agnostic fashion.

The most simplest rational is to distinguish between read intensive and write intensive tables. Probably it is good idea to create two parallel schemas daily/weekly schema and a history schema. The partitioning can be done appropriately. One can think of a batch job to update the history schema with data from daily/weekly schema. In history schema again, you can create separate data tables per website (based on the data volume).

If all you are interested is in the aggregation stats **alone** (which may **not** be true). It is a good idea to have a summary tables (monthly, daily) in which the summary is stored like total unqiue visitors, repeat visitors etc; and these summary tables are to be updated at the end of day. This enables on the fly computation of stats with out waiting for the history database to be updated.

Comment: Interesting suggestion of keeping read and write tables separate. Any specific suggestion why that will be helpful (as opposed to using a queue to do batch writes)?

Comment: Most databases provide a offline export import provision. sqlloader for oracle, db2export/import for db2. I think it is mysqldump for mysql

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely consider splitting the data by site across databases or schemas - this not only makes it much easier to backup, drop etc an individual site/client but also eliminates much of the hassle of making sure no customer can see any other customers data by accident or poor coding etc. It also means it is easier to make choices about partitionaing, over and above databae table-level partitioning for time or client etc.

Also you said that the data volume is 1 million rows per day (that's not particularly heavy and doesn't require huge grunt power to log/store, nor indeed to report (though if you were genererating 500 reports at midnight you might logjam). However you also said that some sites had 1m visitors daily so perhaps you figure is too conservative?

Lastly you didn't say if you want real-time reporting a la chartbeat/opentracker etc or cyclical refresh like google analytics - this will have a major bearing on what your storage model is from day one.

M

Comment: Mark, thanks for responding. The reporting needs to be done in realtime. And that's one of the challenges. You say 1 million rows per day is not heavy. Within 3 years, the total DB capacity will be around 1 billion rows. Isn't that huge? What I am particularly worried about ever-increasing nature of data. We cannot potentially store all the data for eternity?

Comment: Sure you need to do some sizing on it to make sure you have both the storage capacity and the grunt power but with sensible partitioning you should be able to separate out the performance of updates and indeed reporting from being vulnerable to issues as you scale up. You may need to make some sensible choices around building some aggregate tables in there and having the right model to support the BI aspects of what you are trying to provide.

Answer (score 0):

You really should test your way forward will simulated enviroments as close as possible to the live enviroment, with "real fake" data (correct format & length). Benchmark queries and variants of table structures. Since you seem to know MySQL, start there. It shouldn't take you that long to set up a few scripts bombarding your database with queries. Studying the results of *your* database with *your kind of data* will help you realise where the bottlenecks will occur.

Not a solution but hopefully some help on the way, good luck :)