# Want to have a table where a new row is added every month

Tags: mysql, mongodb, graph, database

I am creating a database where every month there will be a new value  entered with the value of the month for graphing purposes. (2 new rows?)

These values need to be recorded with all the other data in the table.

**The question is is it better to use something like MongoDB which I don't know but could learn or stick with MySQL which i do.**
From the perspective of MySQL the table could start to get very big in say 5 to 10 years with 120 to 240 new rows to a table with possible 1,000,000 entries.

Perhaps there is a straight forward design but i am a bit of a newbie to database design..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding 120 to 240 new rows to a table with 1,000,000 entries is like tears in the rain.

Besides, any semi-decent personal computer should be able to handle that level of data assuming the table is correctly indexed and well structured.

Comment: i get what u mean. do you think MySQL would be the correct choice or in reality it doesnt make a difference

Comment: I'd make that choice based on the application and the data itself rather than the amount of data.. MySQL is fine on that scale.

Comment: this article helped too:
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509704/database-architecture-for-millions-of-new-rows-per-day?rq=1)